# How to convert a panel dataset to a multi-layer raster in R?

Tags: r, r-raster, panel-data, r-modis

I wish to use the R package greenbrown to calculate phenology metrics such as Start of Season (SOS) or End of Season (EOS) of Kenya from NDVI values. I already have a panel dataset which includes one datapoint for each 0.5 x 0.5 degrees grid cell for each 16 days since the year 2000 and it looks like the following.

| cell_id | lon | lat | date | year | month | day | period | mean | median |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 33.31259 | -4.76495 | 06apr2000 | 2000 | 4 | 6 | 7 | 5934.126 | 5990.774 |
| 1 | 33.31259 | -4.76495 | 22apr2000 | 2000 | 4 | 22 | 8 | 5648.910 | 5652.855 |

Now as far as I know, I need a object of the class *brick* (i.e., a multi-layer raster object) to use the greenbrown function *PhenologyRaster*. However, I have no experience in converting this dataframe into a multi-layer raster object and wasn't able to resolve my issue online.

Comment: Please edit your question and include example data (created by code, or that ships with R, just as in the help files of R), and use the data with some example code that you have tried and that others can improve upon.

Comment: Greetings! As another has said, usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg